# Unable to create and configure repository database using template QuestlRepository.ntf in quest LNSP migrator console app

Tags: migration, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, quest

I am trying to perform action “I want to create new repository database” from “Configure your repository database” option from “Migrator for notes to Sharepoint setup wizard” in quest tool.

After clicking “Create repository database” button, we are getting the error “File does not exists(Opening database QuestRepository.ntf on server). Below is the screenshot for the reference.
[image]

As per the user guide documentation, We tried to create repository database from the user guide documentation saying ,“NOTE: The Migrator for Notes to SharePoint Console uses a Notes database as its Repository in order to store data that is gathered through analysis and user input. Before using the Migrator for Notes to SharePoint Console, this database must be created using the QuestlRepository.ntf template that has been installed in your Notes data directory. Create the Repository database before running the Notes Database Discovery process.”

We couldn’t find QuestIRepository.ntf file in our notes directory. I need assistance in creating a Database repository and configuring the same.